# SSH trying to login wrong server

Tags: server, ssh, login

While I'm trying to login my server

> ssh 10.0.0.9

I get this error message

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname 10.0.0.**2**': Name or service not known

I have no idea why ssh is trying to connect wrong server. Any ideas what might be wrong?

EDIT:

Here is my ~/.ssh/config file:

```
>  HostName 10.0.0.2
>  HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss
```

and here is /etc/ssh/ssh_config file:

```
> # This is the ssh client system-wide configuration file.  See
> # ssh_config(5) for more information.  This file provides defaults for
> # users, and the values can be changed in per-user configuration files
> # or on the command line.
> 
> # Configuration data is parsed as follows:
> #  1. command line options
> #  2. user-specific file
> #  3. system-wide file
> # Any configuration value is only changed the first time it is set.
> # Thus, host-specific definitions should be at the beginning of the
> # configuration file, and defaults at the end.
> 
> # Site-wide defaults for some commonly used options.  For a comprehensive
> # list of available options, their meanings and defaults, please see the
> # ssh_config(5) man page.
> 
> Host *
> #   ForwardAgent no
> #   ForwardX11 no
> #   ForwardX11Trusted yes
> #   PasswordAuthentication yes
> #   HostbasedAuthentication no
> #   GSSAPIAuthentication no
> #   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
> #   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
> #   GSSAPITrustDNS no
> #   BatchMode no
> #   CheckHostIP yes
> #   AddressFamily any
> #   ConnectTimeout 0
> #   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
> #   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
> #   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
> #   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
> #   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
> #   Port 22
> #   Protocol 2
> #   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
> #   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com
> #   EscapeChar ~
> #   Tunnel no
> #   TunnelDevice any:any
> #   PermitLocalCommand no
> #   VisualHostKey no
> #   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
> #   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
>     SendEnv LANG LC_*
>     HashKnownHosts yes
>     GSSAPIAuthentication yes
```

Comment: Ping works as intended. It pings right server. This seems to be ssh related problem

Comment: Is there something in `~/.ssh/config` or `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`?

Comment: There indeed was. ~/.ssh/config file has host setting 10.0.0.2'. when I removed typo ( ' ) I got this error message: ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to 10.0.0.2 port 22: message authentication code incorrect

Comment: Other than that, there was nothing related to this problem. Only language settings and things like that.

Comment: If your config contains the line `Hostname 10.0.0.2`, you should remove it; it forces `ssh` to always connect to 10.0.0.2. Better yet, edit your question to show the full config file.

Comment: The error happens even if I delete ~/.ssh/config file.

Comment: The fact that you had such an unusual SSH config and were seemingly not aware of it makes it sound like you are in a non-standard environment, like an enterprise maybe. If you are on such a network, you should ask the people in charge.

Comment: I have one Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server and another NAS at address 10.0.0.9. 10.0.0.2 is gateway to internet. I really don't think this is unusual environment. My ssh_config file is default

Comment: It is very unusual to have an SSH config that says "always connect to 10.0.0.2, no matter what hostname is entered on the command line", which is what your `~/.ssh/config` does. You say you have removed it, but apparently there's something else as well...

Comment: I know this isn't a Windows but you could try rebooting at that point :)

Comment: I am running 18.04 as well and I do not have a ~/.ssh/config file. What happens if you remove that file entirely? Rather than delete it just ```mv ~/.ssh/config ../``` to move it up a level

Comment: It is unusual because I have misspelled it. It supposed to read "Host". Thanks for pointing it out, @fkraiem! @Gordster, I renamed file for a while but it did not helped.  After fixing that embarrassing typo ssh works as intended. Thanks everybody for help.